# Selenium IDE - chooseOkOnNextConfirmation without assertConfirmation?

Tags: javascript, selenium, popup, selenium-ide

I'm pretty much new to Selenium IDE and dealing with a JavaScript confirmation pop-up. I want the script to book a table for me but depending on what table I get (which I can't know before) the confirmation pop-up contains different text. Only the first sentence always stays the same. When I use `assertConfirmation` I should include the text as is in the pop-up, right? Is there a way for the script to still confirm the pop-up even if I only have the first sentence of the pop-up as the `assertConfirmation` value? Unfortunately, I can't test the script because the booking is time sensitive and will only be available later. My script looks like this:

```
chooseOkOnNextConfirmation 
click                        //*[@id="table_id"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]/button
assertConfirmation           Are you sure you want to submit your request for the 
                             following unit: Location Description: **{THIS IS NOW 
                             ALL VARIABLE TEXT}**
```

How can I make this work? Do I need the `assertConfirmation` for Selenium to execute my `chooseOkOnNextConfirmation`? If so, how can I make it confirm even without the full text shown in the pop-up as the `assertConfirmation` Value?

Thank you so much in advance! Your help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression patters should be accepted, so you can change as follows:

```
chooseOkOnNextConfirmation 
click                        //*[@id="table_id"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]/button
assertConfirmation           glob:Are you sure you want to submit your request for the 
                             following unit: Location Description: *
                                                                   ^ note - it means all
```

You might find [this guide](https://seleniumonlinetrainingexpert.wordpress.com/2012/11/29/how-to-use-regular-expression-in-selenium-ide/) useful

Comment: Thank you so very much for the very helpful reply! One more question if you don't mind. After I click the button the page reloads and checks for table availability. Only after let's say 2 seconds the JavaScript confirm pop-up is shown. Will I be fine with _chooseOkOnNextConfirmation_ before I press the button and thus the site reloads or should I add another _chooseOkOnNextConfirmation_ after the click during the availability check? It is essential that I get the timing right. Too early and the command might be executed on the wrong page, too late and the JavaScript pop-up stops my script.

Comment: I don't want to be dismissive or anything but this sounds like an entirely different question, in which it would be useful to also see the javascript code, so my advice to you is to ask it separately and provide some more context

Comment: So I tested _assertConfirmation glob:*_ (as well as _glob:Press any butto*) on another site and get the error **Confirmation message doesn't match actual message** in the log. The only way there is no error message is if I put the exact text as a target. Any idea why this would be?